# Fedora won't boot from flashdrive on PC Desktop but will on Macbook Pro

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, fedora

I've installed Fedora to a flash drive (not a live iso) by booting to a Fedora 19 live CD on my Macbook pro and selecting a 32gb flash drive as the installation media.

I'm trying to use the flash drive as a portable linux system, that I can boot to on my Macbook Pro, desktop PC, and multiple PC's at my university. I can boot to it on my macbook pro by inserting it and selecting Fedora from the boot up list. However, when I insert the flash drive to my desktop (Windows as primary OS, has multiple hard drives), press F11 to bring up the boot menu, and select the flash drive- it just boots to Windows.

Comment: what is the filesystem on the flashdrive? UNless its FAT or NTFS then windows will not use it... so it cant read the thumbdrive and boots to the next one in the list.

Comment: What does Windows have to do with it tho? I have Fedora on the flash drive, I don't want to boot to Windows. Fedora formatted the USB drive when installing with standard settings.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood the question.

Comment: Is your computer old? I am not an expert but old BIOS versions may cause some problems. Try to use another USB port, as BIOS may not check all of them. Also, I have read some old articles about maximum size of bootable USB flash drive.